# associate flow of lyrics with song

Tags: qt, parsing

I am creating a music player in Qt. 
One of the feature that I want to implement is that it will show **lyrics** with the song. So I wanted to know about the best suited algorithm which I should use so as to implement this.

I understand that I will have to use timestamp on words of lyrics. But how should i implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sugguest you to adopt the **[LRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_%28file_format%29)** (file format).

**[lrcDB](http://www.lrcdb.org/)** is an online database of lyrics tagged in LRC format.

The **[XMMS](http://www.xmms.org/)** an open source project is one possible good starting point if you are interested in how a multimedia player interprets LCR files.

If you feel comfortable with Python, you can also head to the **[On Screen Lyrics](http://code.google.com/p/onscreenlyrics/)** project hosted on Google Project.